# Errors python2.7 or chromium when build android source tree

Tags: android, python, chromium

I followed the guide of google to build android source tree with fedora 19 64bit. I met the troubles at "make -j4" step with errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../build/android/gyp/gcc_preprocess.py", line 50, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "../build/android/gyp/gcc_preprocess.py", line 43, in main
    DoGcc(options)
  File "../build/android/gyp/gcc_preprocess.py", line 28, in DoGcc
    build_utils.CheckCallDie(gcc_cmd)
  File "/home/hieptv/WORKING_DIRECTORY/external/chromium_org/build/android/gyp/util/build_utils.py", line 91, in CheckCallDie
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, cwd=cwd)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1308, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
make: *** [out/target/product/generic/obj/GYP/shared_intermediates/templates/org/chromium/base/ActivityState.java] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [out/target/product/generic/obj/GYP/shared_intermediates/templates/org/chromium/base/MemoryPressureLevelList.java] Error 1
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Any help will be approciated. Thanks

Comment: May be an elementary question, but do you have GCC installed?

Comment: Hmmm ... what happens if you try without the `-j4`?  e.g. just `make`?  (You'll probably get the same thing after 4 times the wait, but it's worth an experiment, no?)

Comment: thanks for quick reply. GCC is already installed and i also try "make" command but it does not work as the same errors

Answer (score 1):

Only install gcc package is not enough, providing package gcc-4 has been installed, check if /usr/bin/gcc exists, usually it is a link file pointing to /usr/bin/gcc-4.4 for example. similarly, a link file /usr/bin/g++ pointing to g++-4.4 is needed too